# Is vector subtraction commutative?

Tags: vector-spaces

Is Vector Subtraction commutative (a-b = b-a)? And if so how is it visually represented?

My textbook states that it is, but I can't seem to figure out how to visually represent it with the directional arrows.

Comment: Is it true in the vector space $\mathbb{R}$, to begin with? This should give you an idea of what can go wrong in general.

Comment: Your textbook says that it *is* commutative? Have you tried any examples? Pick **any** two vectors in any vector space and try! It is free, so you do not lose anything.

Comment: In addition, I want to mention that Vector Addition is Commutative. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_VaVhs6XDw) is a simple proof of that.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the ground field has characteristic $2$ (and if you don't know what that means, you may safely assume it is not), subtraction is *not* commutative in any nontrivial vector space.

Comment: I will plagiarize "if you don't know what that means, you may safely assume it is not" in the future. +1

Comment: What's a 'ground field'?

Comment: Use $a-b = a + (-b)$

Answer (score 2):

$b-a=-(a-b)$, so $a-b=b-a \iff a-b=-(a-b) \iff a-b=0 \iff a=b$ assuming the ground field has characteristic different from 2 (which is true if the ground field is $\mathbb{R}$, for instance).

So $a-b=b-a$ if and only if $a=b$. In particular, substraction is not commutative.

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, you can visualize this as follows: the arrow pointing from $a$ to $b$ is not equal to the arrow pointing from $b$ to $a$, except in the trivial case when $b=a$.